# Get the base package in Java project

Tags: java, package

How do I programmatically get the base package of a Java project?

For example I have the following:

```
my-app
- src
 - main
  - java
   - hello
    - world
     - util
     - exception
     - misc
```

I want to get: `hello.world`.

Thank you.

Comment: define base package...

Comment: `this.getClass().getCanonicalName().split("\\.")[0]`

Comment: your question is not much clear. Do you want to find out the name of base package in your project? or want to create new package in your project. Please elaborate little more.

Comment: `GetPackageName o = new GetPackageName();
Package pack = o.getClass().getPackage();
String packageName = pack.getName();   System.out.println("Package = " + packageName);`

Comment: @selah1936 If you're going to answer, please do it in an answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @Sun in my example, base package is hello.world; that is the package in which other sub-packages (util, exception, misc) are nested.

Comment: @selah1936 there is no GetPackageName class in standard JDK. It may be from a third-party library.

Comment: @vandench using your codes, it returns "hello" instead of "hello.world".

Comment: @JulezJupiter or try :  `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()`  don't use SPLIT

Comment: @selah1936 Assuming I have Hello class under misc package, then that would return "hello.world.misc.Hello". How would I dynamically/consistently get "hello.world"?

Comment: getPackage() would help. have a look over my answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a class - **Class** , that can do this:

```
Class c = Class.forName("MyClass"); // if you want to specify a class
Class c = this.getClass();          // if you want to use the current class

System.out.println("Package: "+c.getPackage()+"\nClass: "+c.getSimpleName()+"\nFull Identifier: "+c.getName());
```

**c** represented the class **MyClass** in the package **mypackage**, the above code would print:

> Package: mypackage
>
> Class: MyClass
>
> Full Identifier: mypackage.MyClass

You can take this information and modify it in your way.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a class called `HelloWorld` and packaged under:

```
package hello.world.test;
```

then

```
HelloWorld.class.getPackage().getName()
```

will give you `hello.world.test` as package name.

In your case, probably you need to remove the last level as:

```
basePackageName = packageName.substring(0, packageName.lastIndexOf("."));
```

and have `hello.world`.

Comment: Yes. In that case. But that won't work if `HelloWorld` would be placed in another level of package, let's say `hello.world.test.misc` as it will have `hello.world.test`.

Comment: @JulezJupiter How would you define **your base package**?